# Global variable not accessible in different sub?

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I declared projname globally at the top of the module 1. It is assigned in the userform, and is successfully accessed in the createWB sub. However, when I go to access it in the addWindow sub also in module 1, it becomes empty (""). I'm unsure of why this is happening because I thought that since the variable was globally declared I should be able to access it in any sub.

Module 1

```
Option Explicit

Public outputWorkbook As Workbook
Public globalcounter As Integer
Public projname As String
Public projnum As String

createWB()
    Dim uf2 As New UserForm2
    uf2.Show

    Set outputWorkbook = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet)
    outputWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Environ("userprofile") & "\Desktop\" & 
    Replace(projname, " ", "") & ".xlsx"

    outputWorkbook.Activate

    Range("B3") = projname
    Range("B4") = projnum
End Sub

addWindow()
    Workbooks(Replace(projname, " ", "") + ".xlsx").Activate
End Sub
```

Userform Code

```
Public Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    projname = Me.TextBox1.Text
    projnum = Me.TextBox2.Text
    Me.Hide
End Sub
```

Cells  `B3` and `B4` are assigned the correct value, but the `addWindow()` line causes a subscript out of range error. When I test it with `Debug.Print`, I see that projname = "". I also simply tried `outputWorkbook.Activate`, which did not work either.

Comment: It sounds like projname is scoped to module 1 and not global - can you show your declaration please?

Comment: I just added it!

Comment: Could the `.SaveAs` method reset the global variables?

Comment: I think most important is how/ where are you calling `addWindow()`. If you are calling it outside of your whole process then `projName` will be `""`. If you include the caller when you run `creatWB` for example, your `projName` will be stored and you will be able to access it.

Comment: Yes, the problem exists because it seems you are calling them as independent processes. If you include `Call addWindow` to your `createWb()` you will see that you won't get that error because that information is stored based on the `createWB()` routine. Else it is just returning the default state as a ""

Answer (score 1):

### Avoid Global Pollution

Unless there is a really good reason to use them, try to [avoid global variables](https://github.com/todar/VBA-Style-Guide#keep-variables-local). We want to avoid polluting the global namespace. **Captain Planet warned us of that**.

[image: Captain planet]

Instead, try passing your parameters through your various methods as they are needed. This helps prevent errors, makes your code easier to follow, and utilizes composition.

---

### Using your userform to store and expose your properties

Try to instantiate your userform using a `With` statement so that you have a captured instance of it where you have access to its various properties that you expose. In your case `ProjectName` and `ProjectNumber`.

Additionally, there should be a property to check if the userform was canceled or the `X` button was pressed.

You userform would look something like this:

```
Option Explicit

Private cancelled As Boolean

Public Property Get ProjectName() As String
    ProjectName = TextBox1.Value
End Property

Public Property Get ProjectNumber() As Long
    ProjectNumber = TextBox2.Value
End Property

Public Property Get IsCancelled() As Boolean
    IsCancelled = cancelled
End Property

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Me.Hide
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
    If CloseMode = VbQueryClose.vbFormControlMenu Then
        Cancel = True
        OnCancel
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub OnCancel()
    cancelled = True
    Hide
End Sub
```

---

### Instantiating the userform

Here is the example of now calling your userform (*P.S. Change the name from Userform2*). Notice we are capturing our instance of your userform using the `With` block. Within this block, we have access to the properties we exposed: `ProjectName`, `ProjectNumber`, `IsCancelled`.

```
Private Sub createWB()
    With New UserForm2
        .Show
        If Not .IsCancelled Then
            ' Do neccessaray steps here...

            ' You have access to ProjectName and Project number.
            ' Pass this to your addWindow method.
            addWindow .ProjectName

        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

The `ProjectName` now can be accessed from your userform and passed as a parameter to you `addWindow` method.

```
Private Sub addWindow(ByVal projName As String)
    Workbooks(Replace(projName, " ", "") + ".xlsx").Activate
End Sub
```

---

For more information on using userforms in this way see this helpful [Rubberduck Blog Post](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2017/10/25/userform1-show/).

Answer (score 0):

could you try using Module1 as prefix? , jus like in this code

```
 Public Sub CommandButton1_Click()
        Module1.projname = Me.TextBox1.Text
        Module1.projnum = Me.TextBox2.Text
        Me.Hide
    End Sub
```